# case statement in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2012, case

Basically, I want to store a string in a variable. But I want to take some content from other places, like some changing results depending on conditions.

*Example.*
I have 3 students - a, b, c. So here it would be.

```
DECLARE @intro nvarchar(80) = 'Hi!!! My Name is ' + 
          CASE WHEN 'a' THEN 'Ashley' WHEN 'b' THEN 'Bernard' WHEN 'c' THEN 'Cassie'
```

But the plus sign gives an error. I know I can make another variable and add value to it by case statement mentioned above and place it instead of the case statement but I would like to know whether there is any other way of doing that without using a new variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the whole query and the error message

Comment: `case when 'a'` doesn't test anything - what are you testing to see if it is 'a'?  It should either be of the form `case when somefield = 'a' then...` or alternatively, `case somefield when 'a' then...`.  And as mentioned, you have to put the `end` keyword to finish the case statement

Comment: Unless this is a class assignment that's intended for you to learn how to use the `CASE` statement, this looks like a code smell to me. Consider creating a table of names, doing an `INNER JOIN`. Also the syntax for a `CASE` is `CASE <something> WHEN`... You're missing the `something` that will be tested against the `WHEN` values.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CASE WHEN` condition should be compared with 2 values.

```
DECLARE @student char(1) = 'c'
DECLARE @intro nvarchar(80) = 'Hi!!! My Name is ' + 
          CASE @student WHEN 'a' THEN 'Ashley' WHEN 'b' THEN 'Bernard' WHEN 'c' THEN 'Cassie' END 
SELECT @intro
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't comparing anything in your case statement... try something like this instead which compares what ever your student is to the logic you want to check against.

```
DECLARE @student char(1) = 'b'
DECLARE @intro nvarchar(80) = 'Hi!!! My Name is '
SET @intro = @intro + 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @student = 'a' THEN 'Ashley' 
                        WHEN  @student = 'b' THEN 'Bernard' 
                        WHEN  @student = 'c' THEN 'Cassie'
                        ELSE ''
                    END

SELECT @intro
```